# Will this block work as I expect it to work?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, sprite-kit

I have used blocks many times but in this case I have a doubt if it will work.

I have to check a bunch of nodes, to see if they are visible or not. Then I build this method:

```
- (BOOL)areNodesVisible {

  __block BOOL visible = YES;
  [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"myNode"
                         usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
                           if ([node isHidden]) {
                             visible = NO;
                             *stop = YES;
                           }
                         }];

  return visible;
}
```

My problem is that the block is asynchronous, so this method will always return YES.

How do I solve that?

Comment: Is the block asynchronous? Have you debugged to check the thread and if the block is called (the named node is found)? How many nodes with that name do you have?

Comment: How about passing in a block that is invoked once all nodes are checked?

Comment: Are you sure the block is asynchronous?  The documentation for SKNode doesn't say it is, and it wouldn't make much sense to do so, since there would be all sorts of undocumented multithreading concerns…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a block here, you can use the 
[`children`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/children) property of [`SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).

```
- (BOOL)areNodesVisible
{
    for (SKNode *node in self.children)
    {
        if ([node isHidden] && [node.name isEqualToString:@"myNode"])
            return NO;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Or, more simply: `for (SKNode *node in self.children) if ([node isHidden]) return NO; return YES;`

Comment: @AaronBrager If you switch `NO` and `YES` i agree. I'll update

Comment: Fixed.  Also, this approach removes the ability to filter by the child nodes' name.